# Does "Pope to meet U.S. bishops" use the word "to" to emphasize?

Tags: future-tense, headlinese

Does [this news article title](https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/pope-francis-sex-abuse-scandal-1.4819226?cmp=rss?cmp=FB_Post_News) use the word "*to*" to emphasize?

> Pope to meet U.S. bishops amid sex abuse scandal, allegations of Vatican coverup

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not used for emphasis. Headlines follow different rules than the typical, standard sentence. The verb *BE* is often omitted, and *to*-infinitives are used to express a future event (Wikipedia):

> [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) is an abbreviated form of news writing style used in newspaper headlines. Because space is limited, headlines are written in a compressed telegraphic style, using special syntactic conventions, including:
>
> - Forms of the verb "to be" and articles (a, an, the) are usually omitted.
> - Most verbs are in the simple present tense, e.g. "Governor signs bill", while the future is expressed by an infinitive, with to followed by a verb, as in "Governor to sign bill".

You can check the page for more rules.

The title is simply saying that the Pope *will meet*, or *is going to meet*, with U.S. bishops (future). The article clarifies:

> Pope Francis **will meet** Thursday with a delegation of U.S. cardinals and bishops over the sex abuse and coverup scandal roiling the Catholic Church and his own papacy, the Vatican said Tuesday.

It is not a matter of emphasis. It is simply a way to save space in the title, as the Wikipedia article notes.